# How to randomly drop rows in the same group?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the dataFrame,

Team  Rank  Year
0   Riders     1  2014
1   Riders     2  2015
2   Riders     2  2016
3   Riders     3  2017
4   Riders     3  2018
5   Riders     4  2019
6    Kings     1  2016
7    Kings     1  2017
8    Kings     2  2018
9    Kings     4  2019
10  Royals     1  2015
11  Royals     2  2017

I want to randomly drop some rows in the same team with a probability(0.5), and the result might look like this: 
Team  Rank  Year
1   Riders     2  2015
2   Riders     2  2016
3   Riders     3  2017
6    Kings     1  2016
9    Kings     4  2019
10  Royals     1  2015

So, How could I do to get the answers?

Comment: Randomly removing rows from the same group/team, but for all groups in the dataframe, means just randomly removing rows from the whole dataframe. Can you clarify your constraints better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I understand correctly you want to sample within each group:

```
df.groupby("Team").sample(frac=0.5, random_state=2).sort_index()
#       Team    Rank Year
# 0     Riders  1    2014
# 1     Riders  2    2015
# 4     Riders  3    2018
# 8     Kings   2    2018
# 9     Kings   4    2019
# 11    Royals  2    2017
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This is just what I want.